# Complete map of Oceania (physical, from satellite,...) to use as background

Tags: cartography, wgs84

I need to use a map to show a cartographic output based on raster elaborations. Specifically, I want to use this map as background to overlay over it some cells of my rasters layers.

The type of map is not mandatory, it can get from satellites or any other source that give back a nice graphich representation of my study area.

For example, I found this one attached in the post, but it does not include a portion of my interest. This happens for all other maps I found.

Any suggestion for finding online a map complete of East and West Oceania?

[image: Example of the map I want to use; I am not amble to find a map covering all Oceania]

Comment: the linked question shows the steps needed to produce "shifted" map, in your case you don't need to project to Robinson